# Node.js Passing Variables through API

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, parameter-passing

**WARNING:** Today is my first day into learning Node.js, so please bear with me.

I was given an API that allows me to take a PDF file, run it through a web-rendering service so that it will be able to be seen on any browser.  Problem is, I don't know a thing about Node.js

Here's the basic API:

```
var http = require('http'),
    root_url='example.com',
    fileUrl = encodeURIComponent('example.com/myfile.pdf');

http.get(cloud_root_url + 'api/score/view?fileUrl=' + fileUrl, function (err, res) {
    console.log('Got response: ' + res.statusCode);
    // Embed response in a view to client.
}
```

If the script runs correctly, I get a response like this:

```
{
    "result": {
        "session": {
            "id": "alphaNumericCode",
            "viewerUrl": "example.com/api/viewer/alphaNumericCode"
            }
    },
    "status": 200,
    "success": true
}
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how I can plug ANY fileURL in through a query string, or something, and then how I can get this API to export an iFrame with the appropriate viewerURL that is spit out.

Comment: I think you should take a little time first to get a regular node server working that accepts requests and delivers html responses before going any further.  Just try the basic example at http://nodejs.org.  It helps to really get a good grasp of what is going on.  I found with Node that at first it was a little confusing to understand what was happening on the server vs. what was happening on the client since it was all javascript.  :-)

Comment: To get a view for a client, you need to set up a server.